# Checking for the "existence" of version-specific global constants and other features?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very much new to the iPhone SDK. I just haven't been able to find the right search query to find out how to do this kind of checking for the existence of a new or deprecated feature.

Case in point:

iOS4 deprecates **UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey** used for checking the height of the keyboard (and moving, scrolling or whatever to adjust for it). I could still use it but I would like to use the new **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** on 3.2 and above but still fall back to the old one for older 3.x versions.

How do I determine if **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** (a global constant) is declared and exists? I guess that is what I need to check since I cant check if the Dictionary contains the key if the key is not even defined anywhere in the Frameworks for the current OS version.

Any advice on this kind of version checking would be helpful. I am sure I will run into other things as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the Operating System version may be more helpful as it can be adapted for other use cases as well.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion).

It would return a string like `@"3.1.2"` that you could use to check for version-specific features.

Comment: @Martin, you should check the iPhone developer forums at https://devforums.apple.com/, there's lots of information there. It's generally a bad idea to use the device system version to test for the existence of classes and methods, but I don't know of any way around it in this situation.

Comment: OK. So there is no "isThisConstantDefined" or anything like that in obj-c?

For some things, like multitasking, I saw that I could use respondsToSelector on the device object. But for things like these kinds of constant-based dictionary keys I am at a loss.

Using the system version is a bit more trouble than I want though since being able to test it with > or < requires splitting the string into its components and creating an int or float of it. (you can't just cast 3.1.3)

I think for now I will just stick to the deprecated key and update my code when I no longer feel the need to support 3.0

Answer (score 2):

@Martin, here's how I solved it.

```
// Get the size of the keyboard.
NSValue* aValue = nil;

aValue = [info objectForKey:@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"];
if (!aValue) {
    aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
}
```

Using a string constant to query the dictionary for the values isn't recommended, usually, but in this case, `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey` is from an old version of iOS, so it's never going to change.

Comment: I see. That kind of makes sense. The Bounds constant wont change since it is for "locked", already released versions.

Nice alternative.